# Getting Imaging Devices

Tags: c#, webcam, device-driver

I can list webcams in **Device Manager -> Imaging Devices** in windows 8. How can I get this list with C#? And how can I get streams from these items?

Comment: I tried to use WIA but it can not find any webcams...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [DirectX.Capture Class Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library).